# Select box redirect to category page with Username

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I have a select box redirect to a category page which works fine without Username. But I would like to add user "username" so it will redirect and look like e.g. .../gift_photos/category/8_Mart/chris69m in url bar. How can I do that? Thanks in advance,...

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#FormId select').change(function(){ 
    window.location.href = ('/gift_photos/category/' + $(this).val() + $(<?php echo $user_obj['User']['username'] ?>));
})
</script>
```

where $user_obj['User']['username']  is the username

Comment: wrap code inside `document.ready` `$(function(){ //code });`

Answer (score 1):

here is the working copy if anyone needs it,...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
          $('#FormId select').change(function(){ 
  window.location.assign('/gifts/category/' + $(this).val() + '/' + '<?php echo $user_obj['User']['username'] ?>');
          });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for fixing your own problem (the missing /). Note that it's a _bad_ idea/practice to mix js and php. Instead you can, for example, [do something like this](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/6915352)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside a document ready handler as currently jQuery is trying to attach an event to an element which does not exist in the DOM. Also, when writing out your PHP value, you need to wrap it in quotes so that javascript interprets it as a string, not a jQuery object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#FormId select').change(function(){ 
            window.location.assign('/gift_photos/category/' + $(this).val() + '<?php echo $user_obj['User']['username'] ?>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory,... it works! BTW I also add slash,... +'/' in between $(this).val() + '/' + '<?php echo $user_obj['User']['username'] ?>'

Comment: `works fine without Username` - The problem is not going to be solved using `$(function() {` since it already works (FWIW if js is at the end of the page, as it should be, code does _not_ need to be in a document ready handler).